# SVN history lost when renaming class and package together in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When a class and a package that the class belongs to renames using Refactor / Rename Package feature in IntelliJ IDEA (IDEA community 13.1.1) using following procedure file history in SVN is lost.

Approach 1
1. rename package abc -> xyz
2. rename file file_a.java -> file_z.java

```
$ svn stat

D    abc 
D    abc/file_a.java
A+   xyz
D    xyz/file_a.java
D    xyz/file_z.java
```

Note that line 5 above should ideally be xyz/file_z.java A+ which is not the case causing svn history of the file lost.

If you swap the steps, the history is preserved.

Approach 2
1. rename file file_a.java -> file_z.java
2. rename package abc -> xyz

```
$ svn stat

D   abc
D   abc/file_a.java
A+  xyz
A+  xyz/file_z.java
D+  xyz/file_a.java
```

This is not the case with Eclipse (Luna 4.4.2)

What could be the reason for this? We cannot obviously ask developers to use the alternative approach as nobody would remember it.

Comment: I checked the [IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) for this issue, and it doesn't seem to exist, maybe you might want to raise it? Unless you think it's the same problem as [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113536), in which case you might want to add a comment to that.

Comment: @Trisha It is not the same as the issue you have mentioned. I created a [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143680) in their bug tracker.

Comment: This issue is still open in their bug tracker.

Comment: Feel free to add another comment asking for clarification for if/when it will be fixed. If the issues don't get further comments, it's assumed they're no longer a problem.